# How to trigger my function when open a form view in odoo16

Tags: view, odoo, odoo-16

I want to trigger my function when I open the form view for a record. My function needs to get the open record values. I tried to use `_get_view()` but it is not trigger everytime we open a record form view. It is just trigger once when we reload page or first time opening source document(eg,click sale app). Welcome for any suggestions.

Comment: Which kind of function—a Python or JavaScript function—are you looking for?

Comment: @YassirIrfan I want to trigger python function.

Comment: Could you explain your goal, so that we can consider other ways to answer your need

Comment: @sylvain I have two use cases. First is I want to call my API call that is related with open record when user opens the record. Another use case is I used data_encrpytion module from OCA for my new field with password attribute is True. Now this field is displayed with encrpyted value(not my real input value). I just want to store ecrypted value only in database but wants to display my real input value in UI.

Comment: what do u want to do exactly with your API call ? because"open record" may not be the best trigger to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo 16.0, the _get_view Python method is used during view rendering. It returns the fields_views of the supplied views, the fields of the current model, and optionally its filters for the specified action.

```
@api.model    
def _get_view(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', **options):
    
    arch, view = super()._get_view(view_id, view_type, **options)
    
    #Your code here

    return arch, view
```

Comment: I knew _field_view_get() is worked well in odoo15 and trigger everytime we open a record form view. But in odoo16, this fun is deprecated and replace with _get_view() but it is not trigger everytime we open a record.

Comment: Have you tried the _get_view_fields method in odoo16?

Comment: Yes. I did but as I explained in above comment, _get_view() is not trigger everytime we open record form view.

Comment: If you are not using the most recent addons, try using the most recent ones. It ought to function.

Comment: What do you mean? If I am using lastest odoo addons, _get_view() is called every time we open form view?

Comment: If you are facing the issue in your local environment please give a try by switching to latest addons; there is a chance that it could be fixed.

Comment: No. It is not related with lastest addons or not. _get_view() nature is like this in odoo16.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: I appreciate your feedback and understand the importance of providing clear explanations, especially for those who may be new to the concepts or syntax. I have revised my answer to include additional details that should help developers understand the reasoning behind the code.

Answer (score 0):

with `_get_view` function you need to call `_get_view_cache_key()` then only it will call the function when view loading.

Please see below example:

```py
    @api.model
    def _get_view_cache_key(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', **options):
        key = super()._get_view_cache_key(view_id, view_type, **options)
        return key + (self.env.user.company_id.code,)

    @api.model
    def _get_view(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', **options):
        arch, view = super(Student, self)._get_view(view_id, view_type, **options)
        if view_type in ('tree', 'form') and (
                self.env.user.company_id.code == 'ACCA' or self.env.user.company_id.parent_id.code == 'ACCA'):
            for node in arch.xpath("//field[@name='semester_id']"):
                node.set('invisible', '1')
        return arch, view
```